# download file Outside of the tomcat apps folder

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

a "Rookie" question ....

I have this file :
C:/Users/ANTONI~1.ROQ/AppData/Local/Temp/BPCCU/GuiaTransporte.pdf

how can I generate a url to download this file from my wab application running on tomcat ?

http://localhost:8080/mysite/C:/Users/ANTONI~1.ROQ/AppData/Local/Temp/BPCCU/GuiaTransporte.pdf ... is not working ....

Roque

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<Context docBase="C:/Users/ANTONI~1.ROQ/AppData/Local/Temp/BPCCU/" path="/static" />
```

reference would be :

```
http://localhost:8080/static/GuiaTransporte.pdf
```